# Prime factororization with 2 numbers

Tags: c++

```
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
void printPrimeFactors(int n) {
   while (n%2 == 0){
      cout<<"2\t";
      n = n/2;
   }
   for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i = i+2){
      while (n%i == 0){
         cout<<i<<"\t";
         n = n/i;
      }
   }
   if (n > 2)
   cout<<n<<"\t";
}
int main() {
   int n = 263200;
   cout<<"Prime factors of "<<n<<" are :\t";
   printPrimeFactors(n);
   return 0;
}
```

This code prints Prime factors of 26320 are :   `2 2 2 2 2 5 5 7 47`     ,this is output code.

Next
`2*2^4*5^2*7*47 ; n= (2*7*47)= 658` this is square free number , and `p=(2^2*5)=20 ; 658 * 20^2 = 263200` , the first number is my squarefree and the second is all the others that are not exponent 1. How can I do this in the best possible way?

Comment: It is very unclear what the "this" is that you want to do.

Comment: Keep tracking the last prime number you have found. If the next prime number is different then multiply the next to square-free number, and if it is the same multiply to the all-the-rest.

Comment: @Dialecticus that goes wrong with `5` in the example

Comment: To this factorization, I want to add that the code I mentioned works so that a*b^2=c , c is in this example 263200

Comment: Oh, so the first is not "the square-free" but actually "the rest", and second one is not "all-the-rest", but actually "the square". I get it now.

Comment: `printPrimeFactors` should not print anything. It should be renamed to `findFactorization` and return some container with factorization result. Then you can process this result to provide "the square-free".

Answer (score 1):

You count the occurrences of each factor. Any factor that occurs an odd number of times goes once into your "square free number". Divide each count by 2 (dropping any remainder), and that gives you the factor counts for your other parts.

```
std::map<int, int> primeFactors(int n) {
    std::map<int, int> factors;
    while (n % 2 == 0){
       factors[2]++;
       n /= 2;
    }
    for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i = i+2){
       while (n % i == 0){
          factors[i]++;
          n /= i;
       }
    }
    if (n > 2){
        factors[n]++;
    }
    return factors;
}

int square_free(const std::map<int, int> & factors)
{
    int result = 1;
    for (auto [factor, count] : factors)
    {
        if ((count % 2) == 1) {
            result *= factor;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int square(const std::map<int, int> & factors){
    int result = 1;
    for (auto [factor, count] : factors)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (count / 2); ++i) {
            result *= factor;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
   int n = 263200;
   auto factors = primeFactors(n)
   std::cout << "n = " << square_free(factors) << " p = " << square(factors);
   return 0;
}
```

[See it live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a5d1f30fe3a7bb4)